# How do I remove duplicate terms with scores from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a file and below is a snippet of how it looks like. I have these words with an associated score. How can I remove the duplicates which have a lower score. I mean 'fresh' has two score (7.781 and 5.750), I am trying to remove 'fresh' and other duplicate terms with the lower score. Is it possible to so?

```
['norwegian', 7.781341354126479]
['rp', 7.7802465301013]
['fresh', 7.7721646246757885]
['tick', 7.7721646246757885]
['wood', 7.7721646246757885]
['fresh', 5.750711529372451]
['tick', 4.750711529372451]
```

I have tried doing the following to put the file to a dictionary and separate the words and the scores.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d={}
last_seen=set()
with open("scored.txt","r") as filer:

     for line in filer:
            term, score= line.strip().split(",",1)
            if line not in last_seen:
                   last_seen.add(line)
```

Comment: Does your file actually contain the brackets and commas? Also, please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Added. Yes, the file is in the exact same format shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your text file stored strings in format of python lists. You need `ast.literal_eval` to convert string representation to list. And simple `dict` to store scores for teams. Try following code

```
import ast
d={}
with open("scored.txt","r") as filer:
     for line in filer:
            data = ast.literal_eval(line)
            team,score = data[0],data[1]
            if team not in d or d[team] < score:
                d[team] = score
```

UPDATE
To write only team component to file you could use

```
with open("ofile.txt","w") as f:
    for team in d:
        f.write(team)
```

This snippet will write all teams names to file in random order. To keep initial order you should use `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

```
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict
d=OrderedDict()
...
# the same code
```

Comment: If I want to write just the team components to an output file, how do I do so?
with open("ofile.txt","w") as t:
      for x in d[0]:
           print>>t, x

Comment: I seem to notice that the order is not being preserved. The thing is I have ranked these term. Upon removing the duplicates, the order is random. Is it possible to keep them in the same order as before as I need them in the ranked order only?

Comment: @minks Update answer)